# How can I received parameters from a Java program in a PHP function

Tags: java, php

I am trying to make my java program and PHP program interoperable. Major part of the processing is carried in PHP, I need a java program to call a PHP function and send some parameters.

Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: Read about REST and SOAP

Comment: @akasummer a little more decription will help me better. I have tried sending json object to PHP server, but I am unable to read the json object at the php end. May you mention some more specifics.

Comment: Answered your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a wannabe web service on your back-end:

Have some `php` script, that will be processing `POST` requests coming to specific **URL**

```
//in your php script you can access and process your POST data
$somekey = $_POST['somekey'];
process($somekey);
```

From your `java` program you need to create and send `POST` request to that **URL**